# Почему возникает ошибка TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

Почему не конслоится `this` в методе `vue`:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    example(){
      console.log(_.cloneDeep(this));
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div
      @click="example"
    >
      <span>
        Test
      </span>
    <div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Ошибка в хроме:

> TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
>   
>   [Vue warn]:
>   
> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string"

Comment: `console.log(_.cloneDeep(this));` это вы что хотите сделать?

Comment: @ThisMan хмм... вывести на экран объект `vue` в момент вызова метода?

Comment: это понятно, но зачем?) проблема в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425974/why-symbols-not-convert-string-implicitly

Comment: @ThisMan интересно стало. Не понял к чему `url`

Comment: _Не понял к чему_ эээм вы посмотрели какой вопрос по `url`? ваш только более общий)

Comment: @ThisMan Почему там тип `symbol`?

Comment: потому что такова реализация компонента во `vue`)

Comment: скорее почему этот symbol пытается к строке привестись :)